# Eclipse changes my user.name when committing

Tags: git, eclipse

My user.name is set up like this:

LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME (EMP1234)

In my specific case, my user.name is set to "DAVIS, JASON (JRD3428)"

However, when I try to commit, I get an error that says this:

> The User Name: DAVIS, JASON does not contain a valid EMPID. User Names must be of the format 'lastName, firstName (empid)'.

It seems to strip away the EMPID, leaving only LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME. I checked the following in Eclipse and both user.email and user.name are set up correctly:

Preferences > Version Control (Team) > Git > Configuration > User Settings

I also checked git config --get user.name and user.email and everything looks correct there as well. What could be causing this?

Comment: About which name are you talking? Author or committer or ...? Please show the _Staging_ view before hit _Commit_ and the commit in the _History_ view after you hit _Commit_. Please note, that the user settings can be overridden by the repository config and author and committer can manually edit for each commit. Eclipse does not change a commit, but a Git hook can change it.

Comment: The staging view before hitting Commit shows the same for both Author and Committer: DAVIS, JASON (JRD3428) <my email address>.

Comment: And how does the commit look in the _History_ view after you hit _Commit_? Do you really get the error message when you commit it and not later when you push it?

Comment: Looking in _History_, I see the _Id_, _Message_, _Author_, _Authored Date_, _Committer_ (which appears correct) and _Committed Date_. Nothing looks off. I compared _Committer_ to how it appeared two days ago when everything was working, and it matches.

Comment: The error message sounds like it's coming from a Git hook on the remote server preventing pushing. Maybe something went broken on the server side. Does it still work for others using the same repository?

Comment: I was wondering if it had something to do with the remote server, so I just submitted a ticket. Hopefully they'll respond on a Saturday. I don't know if it's impacting any other developers yet.